# CircuiTikZ: How to draw contactor coil?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, circuitikz, circuits, tikz-circuit-lib

It seems the amazing package `CircuiTikZ` is mainly focussed on electronics or circuit boards.

However, sometimes it is necessary to draw some contactor coils for relais, contactors etc. what is not yet available in `CircuiTikZ` predefined symbols.

Is it possible to draw this symbol by myself?

[image: Screenshot of the desired element]

---

**Minimum Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}  
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}

        \draw (0,0) to[twoport, l=$K1$] (0,2);% This is possible indeed, but not a "true" contactor coil...

    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the current approach:**

[image: Screenshot of the current approach]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible using Ti*K*z library `tikz-relay` (https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-relay):

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC.relay}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[circuit ee IEC relay,thick]
\draw (0,0) to [relay coil={info=$K_1$,term=A1,term'=A2}] (0,1);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Off topic, but what a dull relay!  I guess some engineers take pride in NOT being artistic.

Comment: :-). Engineers say that something should be good enough, extremely cheap.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: Actually this is the common contactor coil symbol, at least in Europe. :-) This nearly squared shape from Rmanos approach was never seen here, maybe in the US? :-)

Comment: @dave - European resistors aren't exactly works of art either.  I was thinking more of the fancy coil and stdp switch combo relay symbol.  OTOH, why confuse people with the internal workings?  Sigh!

Comment: @dave, it's almost square because I am lazy and just put width and height randomly... ;-) No standard has been consulted!

Answer (score 5):

In `circuitikz`, you can use `generic` which is a rectangular blob:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
%\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikzgit}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[
    ]
    \ctikzset{relaycoil/.style={bipoles/generic/width=0.3, 
        bipoles/generic/height=0.4}}
    \draw (0,0) to[generic=K1, relaycoil, name=k1] ++(0,2);
    \node [rotate=90, above right, font=\scriptsize] at(k1.right) {A1};
    \node [rotate=90, above left, font=\scriptsize] at(k1.left) {A2};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: relay contactor coil in circuitikz]

Notice that the definition of `width` and `height` are thought for the element in a horizontal position.

Comment: Very good. You should reverse the labels of A1 and A2.

Comment: @Sebastiano thanks, done

Comment: My congratulation for all and I'm always disponible to help everybody. +1.